# Why so slow open remote folder in Tramp mode?

Tags: tramp

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.1

If I want to work with remote folder in dired mode I use Tramp mode.

Ok. It's work... but very slow.

The same remote folders open very quick by Midnight Commander.

Comment: This doesn't tell us much.  Quantify "very slow" and "very quick".

Comment: @phils Remote folder can open about 10 seconds.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions
"How to speed up TRAMP"